# ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event turns off screen

Tags: python, click, ctypes

If I put that line `ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)` in a python script and run the script (double clic on file, start from console, import it in python console and run it), my screen turns off. However, if I run the line directly from the python console, nothing visible happens. This behaviour only started quite recently (before the screen did not turned off).

(If you think it may be caused by the OS/system, don't hesitate to ask for details in the comments.)

Minimal working example:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(4, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, it runs fine but my screen doesn't turn off.  I run Windows 10 Home. What are you trying to do with this?  If you check out the `mouse_event` docs it doesn't show anything that could be causing this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event, are you clicking on something that turns off your screen, or executing another part that causes this in your program?

Comment: Not able to reproduce (*Win 10* + *Python 3.7* *64bit*). How do you get your screen back on? *Win* and *Python* versions? Did you notice the function is deprecated?

Comment: @CristiFati Even so, a lot of C/C++ programs use depreciated calls and don't break, the WinAPI has bugs but it is usually solid enough where it doesn't obviously break

Comment: @Simon: I didn't imply that the deprecated function is be the cause of the current behavior, I said that being deprecated it's best to move away from it (and the fact that a lot of existing programs use deprecated *API*s is by no means a reason for new ones to do the same). Also, if with the other function everything works, there you go: problem solved.

Comment: I'm running python 3.7 + Win 10. I tried it first in some internet page (it was part of an auto-clicker), then on my desktop and in VS Code. As I said, the minimal example causes the issue, so no other instruction were ran and nothing but a code editor and a terminal where running. I get my screen back on simply by physically moving the mouse, like exiting a black screensaver.